# Keeping track of the second result of useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

We have the following scenario. A button triggers a callback method which does some work, then sleeps for one second, and then updates a state:

```
const Component = () => {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState(0);

  const callback = useCallback(async () => {
    // do something
    ...
    // sleep for a second
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    // set state
    setMyState(1);
  }, []);

  return (
    ...
      <button onClick={callback} />
    ...
  );
}
```

I have two questions:

- Is it guaranteed that `setMyState`, the second result of `useState`, is always the same instance of the method? Or do I need to include it in the second argument of `useCallback`, to make sure that the inner method uses the most current version of `setMyState`?
- Let's assume the answer to the first question is "no" (if it's yes, then consider another hook, one for which the answer is no). How can I make sure that the part of the callback that runs after the interval uses the most current instance of `setMyState`? During the 1-second timeout, the component might re-render because of a change in props (or another state), and during that re-render, the instances might change. When that happens, the sleeping method has an old reference to the captured objects.

I have read [Dan Abramov's comments on setInterval](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/). However, it seems to me that he is talking about another problem. In his examples, the timeouts are always short, and it does not matter when an interval is reset. In my use case, it does matter. The method has to run to its end.

Comment: @cbr this answers the first question, thanks, but not the second one.

Comment: If there was a case like that, you'd want to store the setter in a [`ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables), update `ref.current = setMyState` after the `useState()` call and use `ref.current` inside the callback. The `ref` itself doesn't change, but it acts as a box for a value so `ref.current` will always then access the latest setter.

Comment: @cbr thanks, gonna try that.

Comment: If you have a concrete example of a hook where the setter isn't stable (changes each render), do include it in the question for a concrete answer.